# Central limit theorem (the method of "moments")

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to complete this problem. It's been years that I studied probability, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Let $Z_1, Z_2, ...$ be a sequence of IID random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$ and define
\begin{align*}
S_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i
\end{align*}

and
\begin{align*}
L_m=\lim_{n \to \infty}E[S_{n}^{m}].
\end{align*}

Another method of proof of the Central Limit theorem works by showing that for each $m$, the limit $L_m$ exists, and the sequence satisfies the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
L_{m+1}=mL_{m-1}.
\end{align*}

1) Use integration by parts to show that the sequence $R_m=E[Z^{m}]$, where $Z$ is a normal $N(0,1)$ random variable, satisfies the same recurrence relation.

2) Use induction to deduce that the above recurrence relation implies $L_m=R_m=0$ if $m$ is odd, and that they are both equal to 
\begin{align*}
\frac{m!}{2^{m/2}(m/2)!}
\end{align*}

if $m$ is even.

Any guidance at all would be appreciated. I'm not sure where to begin here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Write $u=x^m,\,v=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}$ so $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}uv=0$ and $$R_{m+1}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty uv^\prime dx=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty u^\prime vdx=mR_{m-1}.$$

2) Since $E[S_n^0]=1$ and $E[S_n^1]=0$ for any $n$, $L_m=R_m$ for $m\in\{0,\,1\}$. Thus $L_m=R_m$ for all $m$. The proof by induction that $L_m=0$ for $m$ odd is trivial; for $m$ even it suffices to note $\frac{0!}{2^00!}=1=L_2$, and $$\frac{(m+1)(m+2)}{2\cdot (m/2+1)}=m+1=\frac{L_{m+2}}{m}$$for even $m\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining a bit how you chose your u, v for the integration?

Comment: @mXdX Given that writing the statement $R_{m+1}=mR_{m-1}$ as integrals gives $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{m+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{mx^{m-1}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}dx$, you can't help but notice the relevance of $mx^{m-1}=(x^m)^\prime,\,(\exp-x^2/2)^\prime=-x\exp-x^2/2$.

Comment: And for part 2), how do we draw the conclusion that L_m = R_m for all m? In other words, why does L_m = R_m for m = 0,1 imply that L_m = R_m for all m?

Comment: @mXdX Well, in general: given a recursion relation expressing the $n$th term in terms of (sum or all of) the previous $k$ terms, the first $k$ terms determine the sequence. See if you can prove by induction that sequences agreeing in the first terms, as well as on the recurrence relation, must be identical. (In the case at hand, $k=2$, but only the second most recent prior term is needed.)

Comment: I see. On line one of part 1, you have the limit as x approaches infinity, and on line two you integrate with respect to x. Should these x's be z's? Or am I confused about something else?

Comment: @mXdX Thanks; fixed.

Comment: My last question is -- what is the reasoning behind E[S_n^0] = 1, and E[S_n^1] = 0? I suspect this is simple, but I need to refresh on these concepts.

Comment: $S_n^0=1,\,S_n^1=S_n$.

Comment: I see why E[1] = 1, but how do I know E[S_n] = 1?

Comment: @nXdX You mean $0$.

Comment: Oh yes, how do we know E[S_n] = 0?

Comment: And should the bounds of the integral in part (1) not be -inf to inf, since that's the way the expected value of a continuous random variable is defined?

Comment: @mXdX Thanks; fixed.